# why sometimes reshape(-1,1) and somtimes not in machine learning models?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

When designating X and y arrays in a machine learning model, i see that they sometimes get the column from a dataframe with "values" as in **df.iloc[:,2].values**, and sometimes reshaping it into 2D array, as in **df.iloc[:,2].values.reshape(-1,1)**.

when to use which?

and sometimes i use either way, and they both work. how come the unshaped one works while there is a statement like "The scikit-learn transformers expect input data to be matrices of rows and columns, therefore the 1D arrays for the target variable will have to be reshaped into 2D arrays prior to the transforms."

EDIT:

```
X=dataset.iloc[:,1:23].values
y=dataset.iloc[:,0].values

#%%
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
lr_X=LabelEncoder()
for i in range(0,22):
    X[:,i]=lr_X.fit_transform(X[:,i])

lr_y=LabelEncoder()
y=lr_y.fit_transform(y)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.25,random_state=42)

#%%
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
lr=LinearRegression()
lr.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

[image]

Comment: You need to pay attention to two things - what's the source, and what does the user expect.  Many learning models expect a 2d input, for example (samples, features).  A `reshape(-1,1)` is appropriate if you only have one `feature`.  Learn to identify these expectations in the docs.  And learn to identify the source shape.

Comment: this one is the what i want to hear. thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

**The statement is wrong**.

I presume your source is [machinelearningmastery](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-improve-neural-network-stability-and-modeling-performance-with-data-scaling/) - the statement applies to the `StandardScaler` transformer used in the example, but *not* transformers in general; from the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/1495f6924/sklearn/preprocessing/label.py#L223):

> LabelEncoder(): "shape (n_samples,)"
>   StandardScaler(): "shape [n_samples, n_features]"

So yes, SOMETIMES the reshape is needed (e.g. `StandardScaler`), other times it isn't (`LabelEncoder`). Lastly, `LinearRegression()` expects `X` to be 2D, and `y` to be 1D.

Comment: my friend, i do know what reshape(-1,1) actually. what i am asking is, while there is an explanation like ""The scikit-learn transformers expect input data to be matrices of rows and columns, therefore the 1D arrays for the target variable will have to be reshaped into 2D arrays prior to the transforms.", why does the unshaped one work? or is this explanation wrong?

Comment: @ExcelinEfendisi As long as the data input to the transformer is 2D, it works - what the explanation is saying is, IF it is 1D, THEN it must be reshaped to be 2D. So it's correct.

Comment: the data is 1D, it is not reshaped to 2D and it works. How come?

Comment: @ExcelinEfendisi I doubt that - data with shape `(10, 1)` is _still_ considered to be 2D, even though its _contents_ are only 1D. A 1D array is defined to be something like `(10,)` in Numpy, Scikit, and virtually all major packages. Can you verify this via `print(df...)` (as shown in answer)?

Comment: yes, i added an image in my original post's EDIT part. in line 294, it was supposed to throw an exception

Comment: @ExcelinEfendisi It'd be more helpful if you pasted your code instead (the Variables are fine though) - but based on what you provided, I cannot tell what's the input data to `LienarRegression`. What I can tell is, `X, X_test, X_train` are 2D, `y, y_test, y_train` are not

Comment: by the way, i am aware of the fact that why X is in 2D, as it is a range of columns, which is still a Dataframe, which means 2D, while y is a Series, whic is 1D

Comment: @ExcelinEfendisi To note, your quote only applies to _transformers_ - i.e. imports from `preprocess`. `LinearRegression` should work fine either way. To clarify, what is the output of `print(y.shape)` if you run it _right after_ `dataset.iloc[:,0].values`?

Comment: you r right. so if i only apply fit, it doesnt have to be in 1D. Answer to your question  is (8124,)

Answer (score 0):

Which one to use depends on how you want your data. `df.iloc[:,2].values` will return a single 1D `numpy.ndarray` while `df.iloc[:,2].values.reshape(-1,1)` returns an `ndarray` of `ndarray`.

`df.iloc[:,2].values.reshape(-1)` will return same output as `df.iloc[:,2].values`. So by adding an extra `1` in reshape, you are basically converting every element in array to an array.

Edit:

`clf.fit(df.iloc[:,2].values,df.iloc[:,2].values)` will give an error `ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:`

`clf.fit(df.iloc[:,2].values.reshape(-1,1),df.iloc[:,2].values)` will run fine.

Comment: what i am asking is, while there is an explanation like ""The scikit-learn transformers expect input data to be matrices of rows and columns, therefore the 1D arrays for the target variable will have to be reshaped into 2D arrays prior to the transforms.", why does the unshaped one work? or is this explanation wrong?

Comment: The unshaped one work because it is technically not unshaped. `df.iloc[:,2].values` will return an ndarray of shape (n,) while `df.iloc[:,2].values.reshape(-1,1)` will return ndarray of shape (n,1). If you change the `df.iloc[:,2].values` into a list, then it will fail even though for you it will still be a 1D array. `ndarray` are multidimensional.

Comment: i miswrote it "unshaped". o am awaare thate it has a shape. what i meant is that it is not in 2D shape, rather 1D. please see the EDIT part

Comment: ok now i get it from the code sample. Since it is a machine learning model, they need the data to be in vector format so you have to create it into a (n,m) form but same does not apply for target feature.

Comment: ohh i see better now. so this rule(i mean the explanation in my post) is only valid for feauters, not for the target

Comment: @rajatkabra That's missing the point - the quote only applies to a transformer, imported from `preprocessing`, not `LinearRegression` - difference being, former expects both X and Y to be 2D.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon you r rigth, so if i only use fit, but not transform, i dont have to provide a 2D array. rigth?

Comment: @ExcelinEfendisi Nevermind, I found the exact answer by looking at the source code - see updated